# Why do I get an error when I overlay clips on top of eachother in MoviePy?

Tags: python, moviepy

My "Would you Rather" YouTube Shorts generator thingy got a weird exception.

Here is the log:

```py
topic 1: pizza
topic 2: burger
percentage 1: 69
percentage 2: 42
videospace: testing
generating all of the voices...
successfully downloaded tts voice: "Would you rather?"
successfully downloaded tts voice: "pizza"
successfully downloaded tts voice: "burger"
successfully downloaded tts voice: "Or..."
grabbing music... done
grabbing ticking sound... done
grabbing voices... done
creating audio organization (layer 1...) (layer 2...) done

grabbing all images... 1/3...2/3...3/3... done
generating text... 1/6...2/6...3/6...4/6...5/6...6/6...done
generating timings... 1/5...generating baseplate + topic images... 1/5...2/5...3/5...4/5...5/5... done
generating video organization... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Chalk\WouldYouRather\main.py", line 186, in <module>
    generate_video()
  File "c:\Users\Chalk\WouldYouRather\main.py", line 184, in generate_video
    generate_imagery()
  File "c:\Users\Chalk\WouldYouRather\main.py", line 171, in generate_imagery
    organ_v = concatenate_videoclips([wyapc_v, wyat1_i, wyt1o_i, wya12_i, wyaps_i])
  File "C:\Users\Chalk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\concatenate.py", line 71, in concatenate_videoclips
    tt = np.cumsum([0] + [c.duration for c in clips])
  File "C:\Users\Chalk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2586, in cumsum
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'cumsum', axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
  File "C:\Users\Chalk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 56, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Chalk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 45, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Why did it give me a NoneType error when I just set it to a CompositeVideoClip?

Here's all my code.

```py
import requests
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip, CompositeAudioClip, concatenate_audioclips, concatenate_videoclips, ImageClip, CompositeVideoClip, TextClip

CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
tts_api_key = open("api.txt", "r").read()
tts_voice_id = "pNInz6obpgDQGcFmaJgB" # Adam
tts_url = "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/" + tts_voice_id

MUSIC_START = 50

tts_headers = {
    "Accept": "audio/mpeg",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "xi-api-key": tts_api_key
}

def generate_voice(text, file_name):
    data = {
        "text": text,
        "model_id": "eleven_monolingual_v1",
        "voice_settings": {
            "stability": 0.5,
            "similarity_boost": 0.5
        }
    }
    response = requests.post(tts_url, json=data, headers=tts_headers)
    with open("generated/voice/"+file_name+".mp3", "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
    print("successfully downloaded tts voice: \"" + text + "\"")

topic_1 = input("topic 1: ")
topic_2 = input("topic 2: ")
perce_1 = input("percentage 1: ")
perce_2 = input("percentage 2: ")
video_s = input("videospace: ")

def generate_all_voices():
    print("generating all of the voices...")
    generate_voice("Would you rather?", "wyr")
    generate_voice(topic_1, video_s+"_t1")
    generate_voice(topic_2, video_s+"_t2")
    generate_voice("Or...", "or")

def get_file(type, name, videospace):
    """ I am so sorry for how this code looks. """
    return "generated/" + ("voice" if type == "voice"
                                   or type == "audio"
                                   else "video") + "/" + (video_s + "_" if videospace
                                                                  else "") + name + (".mp3" if type == "voice"
                                                                                            or type == "audio"
                                                                                            else ".mp4")


music_a = None # Music
mcutd_a = None # Music (Clipped)
ctick_a = None # Just ticking sound
tickg_a = None # Ticking sound with ding sound
vwyra_a = None # Voice: "Would you rather?"
vtpc1_a = None # Voice: "(topic 1)"
vtpc2_a = None # Voice: "(topic 2)"
vcsor_a = None # Voice: "or..."
onmsc_a = None # Audio Organization (No Music)
organ_a = None # Audio Organization (Final)

wyapc_i = None # Would you Rather Baseplate
itp1p_i = None # Topic 1 Image
ttp2p_i = None # Topic 2 Image
wyat1_i = None # Topic 1 on Would You Rather Baseplate
wyt1o_i = None # Topic 1 with "or" on Would You Rather Baseplate
wya12_i = None # Topic 1 and 2 on Would You Rather Baseplate
wyaps_i = None # Topic 1 and 2 with percentages on Would You Rather Baseplate

wytxt_t = None # Text: "Would you Rather"
wytt1_t = None # Text: "(topic 1)"
wytt2_t = None # Text: "(topic 2)"
wytor_t = None # Text: "or"
wytp1_t = None # Text: "(percentage 1)"
wytp2_t = None # Text: "(percentage 2)"

wytc1_t = None # Timing Clip 1
wytc2_t = None # Timing Clip 2
wytc3_t = None # Timing Clip 3
wytc4_t = None # Timing Clip 4
wytc5_t = None # Timing Clip 5

wyapc_v = None # Would you Rather Baseplate Clip
organ_v = None # Video Organization

# global music_a, mcutd_a, ctick_a, tickg_a, vwyra_a, vtpc1_a, vtpc2_a, vcsor_a, onmsc_a, organ_a, wyapc_i, itp1p_i, ttp2p_i, wyat1_i, wyt1o_i, wya12_i, wyaps_i, wytxt_t, wytt1_t, wytt2_t, wytor_t, wytp1_t, wytp2_t, wytc1_t, wytc2_t, wytc3_t, wytc4_t, wytc5_t, wyapc_v, organ_v

def generate_audio():
    global music_a, mcutd_a, ctick_a, tickg_a, vwyra_a, vtpc1_a, vtpc2_a, vcsor_a, onmsc_a, organ_a, wyapc_i, itp1p_i, ttp2p_i, wyat1_i, wyt1o_i, wya12_i, wyaps_i, wytxt_t, wytt1_t, wytt2_t, wytor_t, wytp1_t, wytp2_t, wytc1_t, wytc2_t, wytc3_t, wytc4_t, wytc5_t, wyapc_v, organ_v
    print("grabbing music...", end=" ")
    music_a = AudioFileClip("content/audio/music.mp3")
    print("done")

    print("grabbing ticking sound...", end=" ")
    ctick_a = AudioFileClip("content/audio/ticking.mp3").subclip(0,10)
    cding_a = AudioFileClip("content/audio/ding.mp3")
    tickg_a = concatenate_audioclips([ctick_a, cding_a])
    print("done")

    print("grabbing voices...", end=" ")
    vwyra_a = AudioFileClip(get_file("voice", "wyr",False))
    vtpc1_a = AudioFileClip(get_file("voice", "t1",  True))
    vtpc2_a = AudioFileClip(get_file("voice", "t2",  True))
    vcsor_a = AudioFileClip(get_file("voice", "or", False))
    print("done")

    print("creating audio organization (layer 1...)", end=" ")
    onmsc_a = concatenate_audioclips([vwyra_a, vtpc1_a, vcsor_a, vtpc2_a, tickg_a])
    print("(layer 2...)", end=" ")
    mcutd_a = music_a.subclip(MUSIC_START, MUSIC_START + onmsc_a.duration)
    organ_a = CompositeAudioClip([onmsc_a, music_a])
    print("done")

def generate_imagery():
    global music_a, mcutd_a, ctick_a, tickg_a, vwyra_a, vtpc1_a, vtpc2_a, vcsor_a, onmsc_a, organ_a, wyapc_i, itp1p_i, ttp2p_i, wyat1_i, wyt1o_i, wya12_i, wyaps_i, wytxt_t, wytt1_t, wytt2_t, wytor_t, wytp1_t, wytp2_t, wytc1_t, wytc2_t, wytc3_t, wytc4_t, wytc5_t, wyapc_v, organ_v
    print("grabbing all images... 1/3...", end="")
    wyapc_i = ImageClip("content/image/wya.png")
    print("2/3...", end="")
    itp1p_i = ImageClip("content/image/image1.png")
    itp1p_i = itp1p_i.set_position((0.1,0.1), relative=True)
    print("3/3...", end=" ")
    itp2p_i = ImageClip("content/image/image2.png")
    itp2p_i = itp2p_i.set_position((0.6,0.1), relative=True)
    print("done")

    print("generating text... 1/6...", end="")
    wytxt_t = TextClip("Would you rather", fontsize=32, color="black", font="Arial")
    wytxt_t = wytxt_t.set_position(("center",0.1), relative=True)
    print("2/6...", end="")
    wytt1_t = TextClip(topic_1, fontsize=10, color="black", font="Arial")
    wytt1_t = wytt1_t.set_position(("center",0.3), relative=True)
    print("3/6...", end="")
    wytt2_t = TextClip(topic_2, fontsize=10, color="black", font="Arial")
    wytt2_t = wytt2_t.set_position(("center",0.93), relative=True)
    print("4/6...", end="")
    wytor_t = TextClip("or", fontsize=15, color="black", font="Arial")
    wytor_t = wytor_t.set_position(("center", "center"), relative=True)
    print("5/6...", end="")
    wytp1_t = TextClip(f"{str(perce_1)}%", fontsize=10, color=("green" if int(perce_1) > 50 else "red"), font="Arial")
    wytp1_t = wytp1_t.set_position(("center", 0.1), relative=True)
    print("6/6...", end="")
    wytp2_t = TextClip(f"{str(perce_2)}%", fontsize=10, color=("green" if int(perce_2) > 50 else "red"), font="Arial")
    wytp2_t = wytp1_t.set_position(("center", 0.6), relative=True)
    print("done")

    print("generating timings... 1/5...", end="")
    wytc1_t = ImageClip("content/image/timing.png", duration=vwyra_a.duration+2)
    wytc2_t = ImageClip("content/image/timing.png", duration=vtpc1_a.duration+2)
    wytc3_t = ImageClip("content/image/timing.png", duration=vcsor_a.duration+2)
    wytc4_t = ImageClip("content/image/timing.png", duration=vtpc2_a.duration+2+ctick_a.duration+1)
    wytc5_t = ImageClip("content/image/timing.png", duration=2)

    print("generating baseplate + topic images... 1/5...", end="")
    wyapc_v = CompositeVideoClip([wyapc_i, wytxt_t, wytc1_t])
    print("2/5...", end="")
    wyat1_i = CompositeVideoClip([wyapc_i, itp1p_i, wytt1_t, wytc2_t])
    print("3/5...", end="")
    wyt1o_i = CompositeVideoClip([wyapc_i, itp1p_i, wytt1_t, wytor_t, wytc3_t])
    print("4/5...", end="")
    wya12_i = CompositeVideoClip([wyapc_i, itp1p_i, wytt1_t, itp2p_i, wytt2_t, wytc4_t])
    print("5/5...", end=" ")
    wyaps_i = CompositeVideoClip([wyapc_i, itp1p_i, itp2p_i, wytt1_t, wytt2_t, wytp1_t, wytp2_t, wytc5_t])
    print("done")
    
    print("generating video organization...", end=" ")
    organ_v = concatenate_videoclips([wyapc_v, wyat1_i, wyt1o_i, wya12_i, wyaps_i])
    organ_v.audio = organ_a
    print("done")

def export_video():
    global organ_v
    print("exporting the video...", end=" ")
    organ_v.write_videofile(get_file("video", "finalVideo", True))
    print("done :D")

def generate_video():
    generate_all_voices()
    generate_audio()
    print()
    generate_imagery()

generate_video()
```

I was expecting this output:

```
topic 1: pizza
topic 2: burger
percentage 1: 69
percentage 2: 42
videospace: testing
generating all of the voices...
successfully downloaded tts voice: "Would you rather?"
successfully downloaded tts voice: "pizza"
successfully downloaded tts voice: "burger"
successfully downloaded tts voice: "Or..."
grabbing music... done
grabbing ticking sound... done
grabbing voices... done
creating audio organization (layer 1...) (layer 2...) done

grabbing all images... 1/3...2/3...3/3... done
generating text... 1/6...2/6...3/6...4/6...5/6...6/6...done
generating timings... 1/5...generating baseplate + topic images... 1/5...2/5...3/5...4/5...5/5... done
generating video organization... done
exporting the video... done :D
```

And in the folder "./generated/video/", I would get a file called "finalVideo.mp4", containing the video.